# Selected menu item not active in a Joomla 3 multilingual site

Tags: joomla

I am building a multilingual site using Joomla 3.1.5 and am having trouble in getting the menu item for the active page to be higlighted in the English version only.

By inspecting the HTML source I can see that the active menu item (a HTML li tag) has css classes "current active" in all languages except English. In the English version of the site, none of the menu item would be selected. I am totally lost in fiddling with the settings and wonder if anyone has any idea on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. The menu being wrongly shown was the one from "ALL" language, once I unpublished the "ALL" menu, the real "English" menu got shown up correctly with the active one being marked with css class "current active".